# PHP compare multidimensional array to itself and remove arrays based on values within nested array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

There are many questions posted already about removing duplicates or specific values from multidimentional arrays but I can't seem to find anything on comparing a multidimentional array to itself and removing valuse base on the values within the array.

In the folowing example I want to remove any of the arrays where array[0] and array[2] are reversed. So in the example below for the arrays [0] (A,B) and [3] (B,A), [3] would be removed. For the arrays [1] (B,C) and [2] (C,B), [2] would be removed.

```
Array (
[0] => Array ( [0] => A [1] => X [2] => B )
[1] => Array ( [0] => C [1] => Y [2] => B )
[2] => Array ( [0] => B [1] => V [2] => C )
[3] => Array ( [0] => A [1] => Z [2] => A )
[4] => Array ( [0] => B [1] => W [2] => A )
[5] => Array ( [0] => B [1] => V [2] => B ))
```

The resulting array should be

```
Array (
[0] => Array ( [0] => A [1] => X [2] => B )
[1] => Array ( [0] => C [1] => Y [2] => B )
[2] => Array ( [0] => A [1] => Z [2] => A )
[3] => Array ( [0] => B [1] => V [2] => B ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Walk through that array and check every element against every other elements, and if conditions are met then unset that other elements.

```
$array = [
    ['A', 'X', 'B'],
    ['C', 'Y', 'B'],
    ['B', 'V', 'C'],
    ['A', 'Z', 'A'],
    ['B', 'W', 'A'],
    ['B', 'V', 'B'],
];

array_walk($array, function (array $a1, int $k1) use (&$array) {
    foreach ($array as $k2 => $a2) {
        if ($k1 !== $k2 and $a1[0] === $a2[2] and $a1[2] === $a2[0]) {
            unset($array[$k2]);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to just create a temporary container to check if it exists, then filter it from there:

```
$temp = []; // temporary container
$new_arr = array_filter($arr, function($e) use(&$temp) {
    $orig = $e; // create an original copy
    sort($e); // sort
    if(!in_array($e, $temp)) {
        $temp[] = $e; // push if doesn't exist yet
        return $orig; // return the orig
    }
});
```

[Out](https://3v4l.org/C2emU)